Syncfusion Angular ComboBox- Data Source Not Refreshing Based on Another ComboBox Selection
I am using Syncfusion's Angular ComboBox component and have set up a scenario to demonstrate an issue with refreshing a ComboBox data source based on the selection of another ComboBox. Below are the details:
I have created two ComboBoxes:
Item ComboBox: Allows selection of items.
Unit ComboBox: Should refresh to show relevant units based on the selected item in the Item ComboBox
When a user selects an item from the Item ComboBox, I call a reloadCombo() method to update the Unit ComboBox’s data source by fetching the corresponding units based on the selected item key. However, this refresh does not seem to work as expected—the data source of the Unit ComboBox is not updating.
Additional Details
Simple Simulation: For this example, I’ve created a simple service to simulate server data retrieval based on item keys. In the
actual project, I call an API to get unit data based on the selected
item key
Project Complexity: The example provided here is simplified. My real project involves more complex multi-level parent-child
relationships, so I need to follow this structure closely for
compatibility with the overall application. Unfortunately, I cannot
simplify the ComboBox data update logic further.
Methods Tried: I’ve tried calling dataBind() and refresh() on the Unit ComboBox to force an update, but neither resolved the
issue.
I’ve attached a working sample of this setup for reference.
stackblitz example
Is there a specific approach for dynamically refreshing one ComboBox based on another’s selected value within this structure? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You.

Instead of initializing the observable stream this.comdoDataSource again and again with a function call, I changed it to an observable stream using BehaviorSubject.
refreshSub: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
...

...
reload() {
  this.refreshSub.next(new Date().getTime().toString());
}

fetchData(): Observable<any> {
  this.comdoDataSource = this.refreshSub
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.itemUnitService.getUnitsForItem(this.comboRequest);
      })
    )
    .pipe(
      tap((res: any) => {
        this.unitArray = res;
        // setTimeout(() => {
          this.combo.refresh();
        // });
      })
    );
  return this.comdoDataSource;
}

The app component will simply call reload method, where we emit a new value for the refreshSub (BehaviorSubject) using this.refreshSub.next(new Date().getTime().toString()).
This triggers the stream starting from the BehaviorSubject and going to the switchMap which retrieves the data and finally goes to the tap method, where I call the this.combo.refresh(); which reloads with the new data.
If you face any issues with this, just wrap the this.combo.refresh() in a setTimeout and it should work fine.
Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  OnDestroy,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  BehaviorSubject,
  Observable,
  Subject,
  catchError,
  concat,
  debounceTime,
  distinctUntilChanged,
  filter,
  map,
  of,
  switchMap,
  tap,
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  ChangeEventArgs,
  ComboBoxComponent,
  FilteringEventArgs,
  PopupEventArgs,
} from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns';
import { EmitType } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { UnitResponse } from '../../entity/unit-response';
import { ItemService } from '../../service/item.setvice';
import { ComboRequest } from '../../entity/item-response';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-unit-combo-box',
  templateUrl: './unit-combo-box.component.html',
  styleUrl: './unit-combo-box.component.css',
})
export class UnitComboBoxComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild(ComboBoxComponent) combo: ComboBoxComponent;
  selectedDataItem!: UnitResponse;
  itemsLoading = false;
  searchInput = new Subject<string>();
  comdoDataSource!: Observable<UnitResponse[]>;
  public fields: Object = { text: 'unitName' };
  isEditable: boolean = true;
  cssClass: string | null = '';
  unitArray: Array<any>;
  comboRequest: ComboRequest = new ComboRequest();
  refreshSub: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  constructor(private itemUnitService: ItemService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initializeCombo();
  }

  initializeCombo() {
    this.readCombo();
  }

  reload() {
    this.refreshSub.next(new Date().getTime().toString());
  }

  fetchData(): Observable<any> {
    this.comdoDataSource = this.refreshSub
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.itemUnitService.getUnitsForItem(this.comboRequest);
        })
      )
      .pipe(
        tap((res: any) => {
          this.unitArray = res;
          // setTimeout(() => {
          this.combo.refresh();
          // });
        })
      );
    return this.comdoDataSource;
  }
  onBeforeComboRead() {}

  readCombo() {
    this.onBeforeComboRead();
    this.fetchData();
  }

  onAfterComboRead() {}
  reloadCombo(itemky: number) {
    console.log('unit combo reload', itemky);
    // i should reload and update the datasource based on given item key
    this.comboRequest.itmKy = itemky;
    this.reload();
  }
  onSelectionChange(ev: ChangeEventArgs) {
    this.selectedDataItem = ev.value as UnitResponse;
  }

  onFiltering: EmitType<FilteringEventArgs> = (e: FilteringEventArgs) => {};

  onClearvalue(e: PopupEventArgs) {
    // this.comdoDataSource = this.fetchData();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {}
}

Stackblitz Demo

Hi thanks for your response, but I am using these 2 combos inside of a table. It means the Excel-style table I have.  I am giving item combo and unit combo to add a record for that table itself as a row.  In that scenario, this one is not working. if combos have been placed out of a table it is working fine. what could be the issue ??

@buddhichamalka please replicate it for debugging , if possible in a new question
